# How to display a specific list in a component lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, list, iteration, attribute

I have a JSON and I parse it. Finally I this is my class for parsing the JSON :

```
public class InterlocuteursParser {

    public class Interlocuteurs {
        public String contact;
        public String postalcode;
        public String contactnumber;
    }

    public List<Interlocuteurs> Interlocuteurs;
}
```

In my lightning component I have an attribute `Interlocuteurs` (type : List) which is initialized with a `List<Interlocuteurs>`.

I have an attribute called `att` which is a list of String and initialize with `["contact","postalcode","contactnumber"]`.

I want to display in my component the values of attribute for each `Interlocuteurs` in my List of `Interlocuteurs`. I try :

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Interlocuteurs}" var="Interlocuteurs">
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.att}" var="att">
          {!Interlocuteurs}.{!att}
     </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Or

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Interlocuteurs}" var="Interlocuteurs">
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.att}" var="att">
          {!Interlocuteurs.att}
     </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

If I write only `{!Interlocuteurs.contact}` the value of contact of my Interlocuteur is displayed.

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

**EDIT from review queue on 07/14/2018**

Thank you for your response.

If I have Interlocuteur with :
- contact = 1
- postalcode = 51100
- contactnumber = 50

My Component :

```
<aura:component controller="testmecontroller5parser">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute type="List" name="Interlocuteurs"/>
    <aura:attribute type="List" name="getAtt" default="['contact','postalcode','contactnumber']"
    hello: {!v.Interlocuteurs}
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Interlocuteurs}" var="Interl">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.getAtt}" var="att">
             hello : {!Interl.att}
        </aura:iteration>
     </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

But it doesn't work... I want display all values of all attributes of my List Interlocuteurs with iterations.

Answer (score 1):

For client to apex methods/variable you need @AuraEnabled annotation
AuraEnabled Annotation

You may have to annotate every property you are accessing in your component with @AuraEnabled.

The @AuraEnabled annotation enables client- and server-side access to an Apex controller method.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="testmecontroller5parser" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute type="List" name="Interlocuteurs"/>
    hello: {!v.Interlocuteurs}
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Interlocuteurs}" var="Interl">
        hello : {!Interl.contact}
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getInterlocuteurs");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.Interlocuteurs', response.getReturnValue());
            console.log(cmp.get('v.Interlocuteurs'));
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Apex controller:

```
public class testmecontroller5parser {

    public class testmecontroller5 {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String contact;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String postalcode;
        @AuraEnabled
        public String contactnumber;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<testmecontroller5> getInterlocuteurs(){
        List<testmecontroller5> Interlocuteurs = new List<testmecontroller5>();
        testmecontroller5 tst = new testmecontroller5();
        tst.contact = 'contact 1';
        Interlocuteurs.add(tst);
        return Interlocuteurs;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]